# Как извлечь матрицу с координатами вершин фигуры после трансформации?

Tags: cocoa, iphone, opengl

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно извлечь матрицу с координатами вершин фигуры после трансформации командами glRotate, glTranslate, glScale.

Мне нужно обновлять матрицу вершин используя новые координаты после трансформации (сама матрица хранится в переменной объекта).

**Добавлено из комментария**.

```
//Класс фигуры
@interface Square:NSObject
{
   CGFloat vertexData[8];
}

@end

//View for drawing
@implementation OpenGLView
-(void)draw{
    glClearColor(0.78f, 0.78f, 0.78f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glLoadIdentity();
    glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    // SQUARE transformations
    glTranslatef(point.x, point.y, 0.0);
    glRotatef(squareFigure.rotationAngle, 0, 0, 1);
    glTranslatef(-point.x, -point.y, 0.0);
    glVertexPointer (2, GL_FLOAT , 0, [squareFigure getVertexData]);
    //glEnableClientState (GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
@end
```

Comment: Скиньте код, а то это гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, возможно вы имели ввиду матрицу модельно-видового преобразования, т.к. новые координаты вершин вычисляются благодаря ей. К тому же, матрицы вершин не существует.

Во-вторых, в `OpenGL` любое значение извлекается командой `glGet*(type,pointer)`, где `type` - то, что хотите извлечь, `pointer` - указатель, куда стоит извлеченное значение сохранить.

В Си чтобы скопировать, например, матрицу модельно-видовых преобразований в массив вещественных чисел двойной точности используйте следующий код:

```
double mvmat[16];
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,mvmat);
```